# Subject of participle

Tags: grammar, subjects

*Unaware of the foul ball heading towards him, my friend Jim got hit in the head, **causing** excruciating pain.*

I think the subjects of both the participial phrase and the main clause are the same, that is "my friend Jim" in the above sentence.

So it seems that ***"feeling"*** is more natural than ***"causing"*** in the above sentence.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Your sentence could sound as though Jim caused pain to somebody else; it would be better to say **'which caused him** excruciating pain'.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then, how about "..., my friend Jim got a hit in the head, causing excruciating pain?". Is this natural?

Comment: I still think it would be better to include **him**, but perhaps I'm just being pedantic!

Comment: @KateBunting Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ellse No: there is no overt subject, though the subject is _understood_ as the ball hitting him in the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation:

- "causing" is used for cases where: somebody or something is the reason of somebody having excruciating pain.

  You can use this for when somebody attacks you physically, or causes you to be hurt indirectly.
- "feeling" could be also used for cases where: out of nowhere you feel excruciating pain.

  If you out of nowhere you feel excruciating pain on your body without knowing the reason why, you can't say somebody or something causes your pain, instead you just say that you feel the pain.